# 403 Ajax error when trying to place a block

Tags: blocks, ajax

I am unable to place a block. When I click on 'Place Block' nothing happens. When I check the Chrome console, there is an Ajax Forbidden Error 403. Message below. I have both checked Drupal log messages and the server error log and nothing appears there.

I have a local site and a dev site with the exact same code. It works fine on my local site, but not my dev site. All my file permissions are set at 644 and 755. I'm not sure what file I would need to update file permissions for, and if it's a restriction on my host, do I need to add something (and what) to my .htaccess file?

-----------FROM CHROME CONSOLE---------------

Drupal.AjaxError
message: "↵An AJAX HTTP error occurred.↵HTTP Result Code: 403↵Debugging information follows.403 - Forbidden Error↵403 - Forbidden Error↵

You are not allowed to access this address. If the error persists, please contact the website webmaster. If you are the webmaster of this site please log in to Cpanel and check the Error Logs. You will find the exact reason for this error there.

Common reasons for this error are: Incorrect file/directory permissions: Below 644. In order files to be read by the webserver, their permissions have to be equal or above 644. You can update file permissions with a FTP client or through cPanel's File Manager. Restrictive Apache directives inside .htaccess file.  There are two Apache directives which can cause this error - 'Deny from' and 'Options -Indexes'.

--UPDATED: FURTHER INFO FROM CONSOLE--

POST https://........../admin/structure/block/add/block_content%3A9d037523-3c9f-4267-8c94-d41db339b994/uswds_base_subtheme?region=header_top&_wrapper_format=drupal_modal 403
(anonymous) @ VM959:1
send @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
Drupal.Ajax.eventResponse @ ajax.js?v=9.0.8:337
(anonymous) @ ajax.js?v=9.0.8:277
dispatch @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
ajax.js?v=9.0.8:511

Uncaught Drupal.AjaxError {message: "↵An AJAX HTTP error occurred.↵HTTP Result Code: 40…his error - 'Deny from' and 'Options -Indexes'. ↵", name: "AjaxError"}
Drupal.Ajax.error @ ajax.js?v=9.0.8:511
complete @ ajax.js?v=9.0.8:245
c @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
l @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
Drupal.Ajax.eventResponse @ ajax.js?v=9.0.8:337
(anonymous) @ ajax.js?v=9.0.8:277
dispatch @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2
v.handle @ jquery.min.js?v=3.5.1:2

Comment: you'd better to provide more info about the block implementation, without information about what block tries to show that would be hard to say what is wrong there

Comment: That error description doesn't apply to Drupal. In Drupal access depends on the logged-in user. BTW you don't need to place blocks via Ajax if you open Place Block in a new tab. You probably get the 403 there, too, but easier to debug without that extra Ajax layer.

Comment: I updated my post to add everything from the console. I also tried to open Place Blocks in a new tab and received the same error when trying to place a block.

Comment: So Ajax is not the issue and the Ajax error message is not helpful in any way. The question you need to investigate is why does the logged-in user not have permission to access the path to place a block.

Comment: ... or check whether the user is still logged-in. It could be the site is accessible through multiple hosts and the session cookie is only valid for one of them.

Comment: What do you get in your Watchdog logs (under Reports > Recent log messages)? Also, open your browser's dev console and switch to the Network tab. Refresh the page and look for the XHR transaction, then click on its Response tab. Any useful info there? Have you checked your Apache/Nginx logs? A 403 is a HTTP response and its possible that Drupal isn't even receiving the request.

Comment: Watchdog logs show no errors. I am the user trying to add the block. I am the administrator and only user and I am currently logged into the site. Which just made them think of something. The entire site directory is password protected to block access from the outside world. I'm going to look into whether this is causing the issue.

Comment: Nope... Turning off password protection didn't change anything. The error logs on the host also don't show any errors. I then checked the console XHR transaction/response tab. That is giving me the same info I initially posted.